# How do I convert a ColdFusion website to a .NET website?

Tags: c#, coldfusion

This may be too broad, but I have a huge ColdFusion website that I am being tasked to rebuild in .NET.  I've heard that you have to build .NET websites using Visual Studio and it's all set up in that environment, but I would like to keep everything (CSS, HTML, Javascript, etc.) except the Coldfusion.  Can I just copy the pages over to a .NET server and replace the Coldfusion commands with C# commands or something?  Is it not that easy?

Comment: A tutorial on setting up a server and converting a website is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: *"This may be too broad"* It is.

Comment: No, it's not going to be easy. Especially if you don't have a lot of experience in either language.My guess is that someone in your organization has heard that "CF is dead" and got the bright idea to do a simple conversion to a "live" language like ,Net. Having worked on a project like this before, the very first question you should ask is "What do we expect to gain through a conversion like this?" My expectation is that when the effort is realized after a couple of years, this conversion project will either be abandoned or trudged through until it is abandoned half completed.

Comment: I'm pretty versed in ColdFusion, I built the original site (340 pages).  I work for the state, and the state "doesn't support" ColdFusion anymore.  The state does support .NET, and I've been told it needs to be converted.  I'm pretty versed in PHP as well, and if I was converting to PHP, I would just copy the pages to a PHP server and code the commands in PHP instead of ColdFusion.  I had hoped that it would be similar with .NET (using ASP).  Evidently I was mistaken.

Comment: Being very familiar with the original site is a huge plus to being able to convert it, since you already understand the intent of the pieces. Government is still one of the big users of CF, so I'm kinda sorry that yours is abandoning it. I'd still put in the question of "Why? What do we gain?" but with the realization that it would simply be a protest and you'll still have to convert. How many of those 340 pages are actually CF code? I would try to build out the CF pieces you can in .Net. The trick again though is to make sure you do it well. If you don't have a lot of experience with ....

Comment: .... .Net, you may need some assistance to make sure you aren't missing something (like ample security). It still won't be an easy conversion. A PHP conversion (though much more verbose) would be easier than .Net, if that gives you any idea. --- Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at this in the same way one would translate Chinese text to English. It's not word for word, but you have to understand what is being said to rewrite it in another language.
No, it is not as easy as replacing commands. Converting without rewriting would be a bad idea. First, get immersed in the site and learn everything it does. Then, design the new site to use the old code if it is modular. Convert it piece by piece until you are done.